# ejecutar funciones en segundo plano laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo el siguiente codigo

```php
$this->generatePDF($ownerbook, $titlebook, $user->id, $color);
// generar el libro
$tapa = "portada".$user->id;
$this->mergePDFbaja($tapa,$libros,$user->id);
$this->mergePDFalta($tapa,$libros,$user->id);
// envio del mail
$this->thanksbookEmail($user->name,$user->email,$user->id);
// retorno de la vista
return view('thanks.book')->with('name',$user->name);
```

mi idea es que la generacion del libro y el envio del mail se puedan hacer en segundo plano ya que tardan mucho en cargar

Comment: Eso se suele hacer con gestor de mensajes tipo rabbitmq. En tu código envías un "mensaje" al sistema de colas, y luego con otro programa consumidor lees esa información y la vas procesando. Busca información sobre consumidores y rabbitmq en Laravel, eso te puede ayudar

Comment: Puedes usar eventos y como dijo @Jakala usar queues en Laravel

Comment: hay alguna forma facil de redefinir las funciones ya creas para que usen queues?